# Read classic ASP's cookies with PHP

Tags: php, cookies, asp-classic

How do I obtain the asp cookie's name and value using PHP so i may assign it to a variable? PHP and ASP are on the same domain.

Classic Asp Create Cookie

```
response.cookies("apple")("red")="reddelicious"
response.cookies("apple")("yellow")="gingergold"
response.cookies("apple")("green")="grannysmith"
response.cookies("apple").expires = dateadd("d",2,Now())
```

Classic ASP Read Cookie

```
strRed = request.cookies("apple")("red")
strYellow = request.cookies("apple")("yellow")
strGreen = request.cookies("apple")("green")
```

Reading The ASP cookies with PHP echo

```
echo $_COOKIE["apple"];
```

In firebug, after expanding the 'apple' cookie within the console, 'echo $_COOKIE["apple"]' outputs:

```
red=reddelicious&yellow=gingergold&green=grannysmith
```

Tried:

```
$strRed = $_COOKIE["apple"]["red"]; //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function in php

```
<?php

parse_str($_COOKIE["apple"], $apple);

echo($apple["red"]);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the string `red=reddelicious&yellow=gingergold&green=grannysmith` to the format of a multi dimensional array try this:

```
$itemArray = explode('&', $_COOKIE['apple']);  // Split variables at '&'
foreach($itemArray as $item){ // for each variable pair 'key=value'
    $itemParts = explode('=', $item); // split string to '[key, value]'
    $apple[$itemParts[0]] = $itemParts[1]; // set each item to $apple[key] = value; 
}
```

Then you can use the variable like this:

```
$strRed = $apple["red"]; //should work :)
```